# How to encode text into html with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, encode

I have a textarea from I got the value like this **$(ctrl).val()**  then I receive this **%3ch1%3eMy System%3c/h1%3e** so I've been trying to encode this value into this:

```
<h1>My System</h1>
```

But I don't know how.

I found on internet many examples like this

```
jQuery('<div />').html('Some text with &lt;div&gt;html&lt;/div&gt;').text()
```

But no success! The decode text is different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's inherently unsafe/insecure to randomly unescape HTML content unless you know where its coming from (fully).

In any case:

`unescape('%3ch1%3eMy System%3c/h1%3e') = "<h1>My System</h1>"`

Comment: Note that `unescape` is officially deprecated, in this instance you can use replace that method call with `decodeURIComponent()` to the same (but actually, it's not exactly the same) effect.